# How to use testacular with play framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, playframework, karma-runner

I have download the testacular
my project is based on play framework
But I don't know how to write the config.js that match the play framework
Here is something what I know

> framework:play
>
> basepath:''
>
> files:app/assets/javascripts/footageURL.js
>
> cli-port:9000
>
> browser:Chrome
>
> autowatch:yes

Can anyone give me some advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solve it by my self

Here is what I do

1. make sure you have

   - [GitHub](https://github.com/)
   - [npm](https://npmjs.org/)(Node Packaged Modules)
   - [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)(Node Version Manager)
   - [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
2. I download the source code from GitHub
   `:~/Development$ git clone https://github.com/vojtajina/testacular.git`
3. Then you will see a dictionary called testacular .
   `:~/Development$ cd testacular`
4. Before compile this ,you should download require.js
   `sudo npm -g install`
5. After that it should be OK for you to run the source code
   `~/testacular$ grunt build`

Here is [how to write test with jasmine](http://evanhahn.com/?p=181)
and then add the files to the **testacular.conf.js**

Comment: Can you please improve your answer and make it more clear? I need the same

Comment: but you just run the testacular executable on your project folder? or have you automatized it through your Project.scala or Build.scala ?

Comment: You can see [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVw8N3hTfCI) which tells you how to automatize testacular through your Project. And [this](http://testacular.github.com/0.6.0/index.html) give you more information